# visual studio 2013 search replace regular expression to add new parameter

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I want to add a parameter to all functions calls

```
Public Function GetAllOrderBySearch(.... (.....
```

there can be another parentheses in the function call as a parameter like list (of integer)

```
Public Function GetAllOrderBySearch(byref newparam as type, ........
```

I tried public function .* \( but its grabbing the latest (.

been trying to figure this out for an hour now, I feel like a noob.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function .*?\(
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are trying to add a parameter, like below, follow this pattern:

```
MyFun(i, j) --> MyFun(i, j, k)
```

Find What:

```
(MyFunctionName\(.*?)(\))
```

Replace With:

```
$1, MyParamName$2
```

The left side is enclosed in parenthesis, so is the right side. $1 and $2 specify the left and right sides respectively. .*? means everything in the middle before a parenthesis.